How can I achieve 2FA auth based on wildfly elytron?
I'd like create an application whit capable of MFA. Password and OTP can be enough good for us.
We don't find any solution of it. There are

'aggregate realm' but just multi authorization
'failover realm' but just if first realm doesn't work
'distributed realm' but just if user is in first realm than auth first else second

I have to write custom realm, I can't use wildfly standard for this?

Any way you could put Keycloak in front of Wildfly?  They work very well together.

Yes, it is one way. But we search an simpler, another solution. We use some single monolits, why must we put another quarkus before wildfly? With Jaas we could define Yubico like this: https://developer.jboss.org/docs/DOC-53085

It has come an idee to my mind... There can be an aggregate realm. Authentication with password, and authorization realm just with OTP. Without OTP can looged in without any role. Is any OTP realm for elytron?
